# Is github pages intended to be merged into master?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

The gh-pages branch feels like an abuse of the branching system. An indication is the ahead/behind information in the brach overview, which is somehow nonsense.

Comment: What sort of answer do you expect to get here? Yes, it's probably not what the branching system was originally designed for, but it works fine and is a useful feature.

Comment: I expect to get either a definitve no and a why. Or a yes and a guide or some tips how to achieve it.

Comment: Achieve what? It's clear you shouldn't merge it into master.

Comment: Extactly this is the reason why I ask. Why on earth should this be clear. Rather the contrary...

Comment: You merge branches together when you want the branched code in the other branch. Since you generally don't want your `gh-pages` stuff in the main repository branch, why would you merge it?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r what's the point ? Your question is _nonsense_ just as *gh-pages* branch is nonsense from an academic point of view on versioning systems. But, that's the way it is, and if you have a clever question to ask, we'll be pleased to answer. But please, try to elaborate a bit more on the clever side.

Comment: If one could merge, it would not be nonsense from an academic point of view, my question would not be nonsense. Since I dont know if I can merge, I dont know if my question is nonsense or not. To definitively know if my thoughts are nonsense or not, I post a question here. I got an answer, I am satisfied. Maybe it will help other people. This is what SO is all about, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, it is not intended to be merged to `master`. It will live its own life on the side. It is not an error to create branches that are history-wise unrelated. If you prefer it to have no common history you may create the branch using the `--orhan` option to `git checkout`. More information: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout